# In delphi how do I create a string with null separator

Tags: string, delphi, null, shfileoperation

I am using SHFileOperation and the source can be a pwidechar with filenames separated by a null and the whole thing terminated with a double null.

I can create an array of widechar and it holds the information I need but when I try to convert to pwidechar for the function, it only copies to the first null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
const
  null = #0;

var
  FileNames: string;
...
FileNames := FileName1 + null + FileName2 + null;
```

Then pass `PWideChar(FileNames)` to `SHFileOperation`.

Because Delphi strings are automatically null-terminated, `PWideChar(FileNames)` is double null-terminated. One null-terminator that we put on the end, and the automatically added one.

Note that I am assuming that you are using a Unicode Delphi since you talk about wide characters. If you are on an older Delphi, and are calling `SHFileOperationW`, then declare `FileNames` to be `WideString`.

More likely you have a list of files in, say, a string list. Treat them like this:

```
var
  FileNames: string;
...
if FileList.Count=0 then
  FileNames := null
else
begin
  FileNames := '';
  for i := 0 to FileList.Count-1 do
    FileNames := FileNames + FileList[i] + null;
end;
```

Comment: I apologise for the early version of this answer that used '\0', which would have been fine if the language in question was C or C++ !!?!

Comment: Oops, you were editing while I was replying.  It's all good now :)

Comment: I'm sorry about that @Daniel, I don't know what came over me!

Comment: The null-separated string is expected to be double-null-terminated so there should be one final null appended after the loop.

Comment: @TOndrej No there should not. Delphi strings are already null terminated, so adding another one would make three in total.

Comment: They are terminated with one null, so you need to append another to make it double-null-terminated. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are missing something. Read the text again, the paragraph beginning "because".

Comment: @TOndrej On the other hand, my original version did not double null terminate in the case where the list is empty

Comment: `null` is not good name for constant (think about `Null` function for variants).

Comment: I have this wrapped in a function `function NullDelStr(AStrings: TStrings): String;`. which doesn't use any constant (to avoid confusion @Victoria )